# Project entire document from mongo by max created date time

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have created this query to get all documents within a certain date time frame by their max creation date time. I am looking for a list of all the latest documents for each hour.

```py
pipe = [
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "start": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$StartTime",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
        }
      },
      "created": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$CreatedDateTime",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "start": {
        "$gte": start_time,
        "$lte": end_time
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "created": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$start",
      "doc": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  }
]
cursor = COLLECTION.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
```

However since I am using `$addFields` I am also projecting `start` and `created` which I am not looking for. Can I replicate this query in a way to exclude those fields and only include the original document. I am also wondering if maybe this isn't the most optimal query for my solution so any input or suggestions are welcome.

This is a sample document:

```
{
  "StartTime" : "2020-05-01T00:00:00-05:00",
  "EndTime" : "2020-05-01T00:59:59-05:00",
  "Value" : 100,
  "CreatedDateTime" : "2020-05-01T00:00:00-05:00"
}
```

This is what the query returns if i were to query for say one hour:

```
{
  "StartTime" : "2020-05-01T00:00:00-05:00",
  "EndTime" : "2020-05-01T00:59:59-05:00",
  "Value" : 100,
  "CreatedDateTime" : "2020-05-01T00:00:00-05:00",
  "start" : datetime.datetime(2020,05,01),
  "created" : datetime.datetime(2020,05,01)
}
```

The result I am looking for is the sample document or a list of sample documents if I were to query for multiple hours.

Comment: Please edit this post with sample doc & required o/p..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `$addFields` stage in you aggregation pipeline. Just convert `start_time` and `end_time` to string. Replace `start` with `StartTime` and `created` with `CreatedDateTime`.

So, finally your query should look like below:

```py
pipe = [{
  "$match": {
    "StartTime": {
      "$gte": start_time,
      "$lte": end_time
    }
  }
},
{
  "$sort": {
    "CreatedDateTime": -1
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$StartTime",
    "doc": {
      "$first": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$doc"
  }
}]
cursor = COLLECTION.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
```

In my case, I initialized `start_time` and `end_time` like below:

```py
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.strptime('01 May 2020 00:00:00-05:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%z').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') # Value: 2020-05-01T00:00:00-05:00
start_time = start_time[:-2]+':'+start_time[-2:]
end_time = datetime.strptime('01 May 2020 00:59:59-05:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%z').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') # Value: 2020-05-01T00:59:59-05:00
end_time = end_time[:-2]+':'+end_time[-2:]
```

You can do some modification like above, and run the query.

**Short Explanation:** String comparison is done in lexicographical way. So, `"01"` is less than `"02"`, `"03"` is greater than `"01"`, similarly, `"2020-05-01 00:00:00-05:00"` is less than equal to `"2020-05-01T00:00:00-05:00"` and `"2020-05-01 00:59:59-05:00"` is greater than equal to `"2020-05-01T00:00:00-05:00"`.

I hope the above helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this solution but I dont believe it is comparing by time. When I input two different days i get a response but when I input the same day different time it is not able to return any documents. I dont think it is comparing at the hour/minute/second level and only comparing at year/month/day.

Comment: Could you provide that test case, may be I can improve this?

Comment: For the same start_time and end_time you have in your answer it does not return any value. If i were to change end_time to 02 May it would return all hours for the first of May. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue because the logic seems sound. Must be something with comparing string dates.

Comment: Could you make sure that, both dates are provided in the same format : `'%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%z`?

Comment: Yes I am initializing start_time and end_time as in your answer and in the debugger i can see start_time as '2020-02-07 00:00:00-05:00' and end_time as '2020-02-07 00:59:59-05:00' being passed to the query (dates i using as an example that i have in mongo) and the result is an empty list []. However changing end_time to 2020-02-08 returns all of 2020-02-07 hours.

Comment: start_time = str(datetime.strptime('07 Feb 2020 00:00:00-05:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%z')) and
end_time = str(datetime.strptime('07 Feb 2020 00:59:59-05:00', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%z')) like so

Comment: OK, could you post that sample data? I am shocked, its working for me.

Comment: {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ec00a2df96d8a6234a837ae"),
  "StartTime" : "2020-02-07T00:00:00-05:00",
  "EndTime" : "2020-02-07T00:59:59-05:00",
  "CreatedDateTime" : "2020-05-11T10:41:49-05:00",
  "Value" : 6.20263464677081
} This is the object im trying to return

Comment: After intensive research, I found that there `datetime` format was not matching. I just made changes, on how to initialize `start_time` and `end_time`, please go through it and let me know.

Comment: When i format like that it returns '2020-02-07T00:00:00-0500' and its not able to compare it to '2020-02-07T00:00:00-05:00'

Comment: I guess i can explicitly use .strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-05:00')

Comment: But what if in db something like -04:00 is there, it will convert it to -05:00.

Comment: I would rather not use -05:00 but otherwise its returning -0500 and it fails to compare it. I am only storing the offset as -05:00 so it is no big deal. Thank you for all your help i appreciate the research you did for this question:)!

Comment: I just updated my answer to get the datetime in required format.